# I have designed how my app would look like,,but I don't know what exactly the feature is called

Tags: android

If I like a feature in an android app, and want to use the same in mine, how would I know what's that feature called? and so how to search for it!?
I want to include one feature of elevate (a brain training android app)...
As its countdown , it uses its background. I want to include that kind of timer in my app.

Comment: are you developing app like question answer??

Comment: No, I am developing a game that has got a time limit.

Comment: use http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html